# Syntax checking for Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Is it possible? For instance,
if I type

```
std::cout << "cool"
```

without the semicolon
are there any vis studio plugins which will catch that (the way eclipse does) or similar syntactical errors and show me the error visually?

Comment: Vs does this by default.

Comment: How is "The way eclipse does" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [VisualAssistX](http://www.wholetomato.com/), which enables a more sophisticated intellitype system than the standard VC.

Comment: There is far less justification for this than there used to be.  As noted in comments the IDE highlights this error and many others by default.

Comment: This might be, but in my opinion, the built-in C++ intellisense is not sufficient. I think the OP means, that in eclipse you do have to compile the program in order to visualize the errors. This is not true for VS, unfortunately not even with VAX.

Comment: @Constantinus - What do you mean, is it a **disadvantage** that the error is shown immediately?

Comment: of course not, it is a sophisticated feature, most IDEs lack (regarding C++). This feature is lacking in VS. That was what I meant.

Comment: Then I guess I really have to give VS 2010 a try :)

Comment: @Constantinius - I am using the Express free download, that's where I did this little test.  It's also a nice upgrade due to inclusion of some C++0x features.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, Visual Studio 2010 does this by default.  The offending code is underlined, and when you hover over it, the IDE tells you what's wrong.  eg. for the following:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "cool"
}
```

I get the closing brace underlined and the message is "Error: expected a ;"

Comment: I think @colton needs the plugin called "upgrade to latest version" to get latest features.

Comment: @Bo - ah yes, looks like this is new in VS2010. Updating this answer and +1 for the other.

Comment: Yes... Well I am working at a software development studio that does not have the latest version of Visual Studio... Can you do serious development in the express version?

Comment: @Colton - yes, you can but I would not recomend you diverge from your coworkers. Try to get them to buy the addin suggested.